# Reaching the result then returns to the initial state

Tags: list, prolog

So I'm in the process of learning prolog.

All I want to do is to change the order of elements and get the new list as result.

When tracing the solution I get to the right answer, however once I reach the base case Prolog starts to empty the list again and returns and empty list as a result.

**Code:**

```
accRev([], [], _) :- !.
accRev([], A, R) :- accRev(A, [], R), !.
accRev([H, H2 |T], A, R):-
  append(R, [H], R1),
  append(A, [H2], A1),
  accRev(T, A1, R1), !.
accRev([H], A, R):-
  append(R, [H], R1),
  accRev(A, [], R1), !.

accRevT([], [], _) :- !.
accRevT([], A, R) :- accRev(A, [], R), !.
accRevT([H, H2 |T], A, R):-
  append(R, [H], R1),
  append(A, [H2], A1),
  accRevT(T, [H2 | A], [H | R]), !.
accRevT([H], A, R):-
  append(R, [H], R1),
  accRevT(A, [], [H | R]), !.
```

**Image of the trace**

Note how it reaches accRev([], [], [1, 3, 2, 4]) (this is what I would like R to become, R = [1, 3, 2, 4])

[image]

**So whats wrong?**

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15259282/1812457). You should _not_ have an anonymous variable `_` in your end-of-recursion clause when you use accumulators. The clause usually reads `foo([], Acc, Acc).`, not `foo([], [], _).`

Comment: Another major issue with your code: way too many cuts. Do you really know what each of them does? Do you know if leaving them out changes the program?

Comment: What exactly do you want as output-What is the purpose of your program because "change the order of elements" is not very clear...

Answer (score 0):

If understood correctly what you're trying to do you could write:

```
  accRev([],[]).
  accRev([X|Y], Lout):-
    split_list([X|Y],Z1),
    split_list(Y,Z2),
    accRev(Z2,Z3),
    append(Z1,Z3,Lout).


split_list([],[]).
split_list([X|[]], [X]).
split_list([X,_|T], [X|R]):-split_list(T,R).
```

Example:

```
?- accRev([1,2,3,4],R).
R = [1, 3, 2, 4] ;
false.
```

In your solution I think some problems were caused due to use of too many cuts and `accRev([], [], _)` as Boris wrote, and also I think you don't need the middle list because for example the clauses:

```
accRev([], [], _) :- !.
accRev([], A, R) :- accRev(A, [], R), !.
```

will lead to problems since if the  first list is the empty list both clauses match.